# Isometric embedding of $\ell^2$ into $L_1$.

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory

Let $\{Y_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of i.i.d. random variables on some probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ following a standard complex Gaussian distribution (that is, the variables may take complex values). Then I have been told that the mapping
$T : \ell^2 \to L_1(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ given by
\begin{align*}
T(\{x_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x_n Y_n
\end{align*}
is an isometry. Can someone help me establish this? I guess that I want to show that the $\ell^2$-norm of $\{x_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is always equal to the integral of the absolute value of the sum (where we integrate with respect to $P$), but I cannot see why this is always the case.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear to me that it's literally an isometry. It's a scalar multiple of an isometry; I'll let you do the calculus to determine the constant by looking at the sequence $(1,0,0,\dots)$.

This follows from the fact that $$\sum_{n=1}^Nx_nY_n$$is normal with standard deviation $\left(\sum|x_n|^2\right)^{1/2}.$ (If you didn't know that, consider the characteristic function. That is, the characteristic function regarding all these random variables as $\Bbb R^2$-valued.)